# Is it possible to save an excel file in local storage and manipulate its data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, local-storage

I am working on a web plateforme that displays different statistics from an excel file in the server.
For a better performance, I want to download the excel file into local storage so the browser does not have to call the server for each action performed by the user.
The file size varies between 200Ko and 2Mo.
Is there an easy way to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: can you try this  https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: yes you could use local storage too.

Comment: `2MB` `into local storage` that may hit the limit of some browsers

Comment: Some browsers also support Indexed DB and Web SQL DB - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage